# Looping to get basic stats

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way (code) to speed some of my routines in R. Since I've no skills with programming, I'm trying some help herein...

The question is: how can a use/set up a loop to get the mean (actually I'm looking for the weighted mean, as computed by the function 'weighted.mean {stats}': http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/weighted.mean.html) for each group (sample) that is defined by the combination of the levels of the variables 'spp' and 'local', for all the predictors ('duration', 'initial.time', 'freq.initial', and 'freq.min'). 'n.indiv' is the number of individuals sampled at each locality, for each species, and is the weight to be applied for each sample to get the weighted means (the data is pseudo-replicated, since the same individual was, in most cases, sampled twice or more times - see 'id.indiv').

What am I expecting(?): the weighted mean for the species 'Aae' at locality 'FO' (for all predictors); the weighted mean for the species 'Aae' at locality 'MA' (for all predictors); the weighted mean for the species 'Aar' at locality 'FO' (for all predictors); and so on (until I get the weighted mean for the species 'Pma' at locality 'FO').

Thanks in advance for anyone who spared some time reading and/or trying to solve the problem.

---

### The data:

```
spp id.indiv    local   n.indiv duration    initial.time    freq.initial    freq.min
Aae 1   FO  2   297 45.446  438 438
Aae 1   FO  2   296 46.438  383 383
Aae 1   FO  2   311 117.406 481 471
Aae 1   FO  2   276 118.537 503 463
Aae 1   FO  2   289 119.545 466 433
Aae 2   FO  2   288 4.469   445 412
Aae 2   FO  2   291 7.28    412 396
Aae 2   FO  2   277 8.218   370 370
Aae 3   MA  2   309 0.227   453 453
Aae 3   MA  2   314 1.876   350 350
Aae 3   MA  2   343 4.977   373 373
Aae 3   MA  2   312 15.283  445 445
Aae 3   MA  2   336 11.77   445 445
Aae 4   MA  2   317 4.154   431 431
Aae 4   MA  2   334 20.555  431 431
Aae 4   MA  2   325 13.903  454 454
Aae 4   MA  2   337 8.482   427 380
Aae 4   MA  2   338 10.586  443 388
Aar 1   FO  3   286 15.029  273 242
Aar 1   FO  3   239 20.61   381 381
Aar 2   FO  3   243 34.077  335 335
Aar 2   FO  3   516 43.662  345 301
Aar 3   FO  3   302 5.458   391 287
Aar 3   FO  3   553 9.746   426 252
Aar 3   FO  3   196 33.127  444 313
Aar 3   FO  3   273 39.578  374 252
Aar 4   FO  3   326 46.674  357 315
Aar 5   FO  3   495 8.445   295 240
Aau 1   FO  3   195 2.954   794 794
Aau 1   FO  3   207 17.324  758 758
Aau 1   FO  3   294 19.726  712 712
Aau 2   FO  3   203 17.049  762 762
Aau 2   FO  3   195 29.086  750 750
Aau 2   FO  3   196 45.24   708 708
Aau 3   FO  3   245 13.669  628 628
Aau 4   FO  3   265 104.038 883 883
Aau 5   FO  3   217 6.853   791 791
Aau 6   MA  3   173 0.369   713 713
Aau 6   MA  3   148 1.942   611 611
Aau 7   MA  3   174 1.963   482 482
Aau 7   MA  3   180 2.306   551 551
Aau 7   MA  3   180 3.835   505 505
Aau 8   MA  3   173 4.346   759 759
Aau 8   MA  3   177 11.864  777 777
Aau 8   MA  3   155 17.799  653 653
Aau 8   MA  3   163 40.313  635 635
Ale 1   FO  3   191 6.306   784 784
Ale 3   FO  3   194 3.158   650 650
Ale 3   FO  3   215 3.875   710 710
Ale 3   FO  3   208 4.22    592 592
Ale 3   FO  3   216 5.826   645 645
Ale 4   FO  3   225 113.572 730 730
Axa 1   BS  2   237 58.593  1561    480
Axa 1   BS  2   226 101.23  1029    432
Axa 1   BS  2   234 102.57  1064    460
Axa 1   BS  2   230 103.883 1038    429
Axa 2   BS  2   212 29.2    783 476
Axa 2   BS  2   202 19.005  1154    544
Axa 2   BS  2   190 23.161  956 742
Axa 2   BS  2   201 44.778  841 511
Axa 3   EM  3   176 0.175   1075    677
Axa 4   EM  3   184 0.134   700 646
Axa 4   EM  3   206 0.148   661 505
Axa 4   EM  3   189 0.148   827 535
Axa 4   EM  3   196 0.146   693 488
Axa 5   EM  3   203 0.136   780 420
Axa 5   EM  3   193 0.15    823 450
Axa 5   EM  3   199 0.148   1257    509
Axa 5   EM  3   206 0.123   897 437
Axa 5   EM  3   209 0.136   586 479
Bch 4   MA  3   123 6.231   1010    1010
Bch 4   MA  3   119 15.92   945 945
Bch 4   MA  3   121 20.847  1053    1053
Bch 5   MA  3   127 9.622   1111    1111
Bch 5   MA  3   135 19.766  1184    1184
Bch 5   MA  3   130 25.728  1304    1304
Bch 6   MA  3   144 4.391   1448    1448
Bch 6   MA  3   148 8.583   1107    1107
Bch 6   MA  3   149 8.816   1031    1031
Bch 1   UN  3   116 4.544   997 997
Bch 1   UN  3   123 10.011  906 906
Bch 1   UN  3   127 12.204  1133    1133
Bch 2   UN  3   124 4.871   1074    1074
Bch 2   UN  3   129 9.811   1198    1198
Bch 2   UN  3   122 2.151   1198    1198
Bch 3   UN  3   105 1.732   1266    1266
Bch 3   UN  3   102 4.67    928 928
Bch 3   UN  3   112 8.278   1034    1034
Dno 1   FO  2   223 11.763  296 296
Dno 1   FO  2   206 12.107  444 444
Dno 1   FO  2   207 123.724 336 336
Dno 1   FO  2   211 124.216 350 350
Dno 2   FO  2   193 20.527  511 511
Dno 2   FO  2   180 20.813  518 518
Dno 2   FO  2   182 26.485  423 423
Dno 2   FO  2   207 26.77   483 483
Dno 2   FO  2   188 56.531  518 518
Dno 2   FO  2   217 56.828  483 483
Dno 3   MA  2   209 6.245   346 346
Dno 3   MA  2   197 6.636   449 449
Dno 3   MA  2   202 10.656  456 456
Dno 3   MA  2   219 13.031  347 347
Dno 4   MA  2   161 110.292 488 488
Dno 4   MA  2   181 118.696 527 527
Dno 4   MA  2   156 136.282 537 537
Dno 4   MA  2   155 136.021 567 567
Fxa 1   FO  3   78  0.335   1700    1700
Fxa 1   FO  3   78  0.459   1758    1758
Fxa 1   FO  3   97  1.132   1873    1873
Fxa 1   FO  3   79  1.307   1672    1672
Fxa 1   FO  3   76  2.996   1858    1858
Fxa 2   FO  3   118 4.612   1203    1203
Fxa 2   FO  3   118 6.125   1063    1063
Fxa 2   FO  3   102 8.55    1231    1231
Fxa 3   FO  3   115 0.106   1604    1604
Fxa 3   FO  3   126 2.325   1363    1363
Fxa 3   FO  3   84  2.893   1931    1931
Fxa 4   UN  3   114 0.443   2224    2224
Fxa 4   UN  3   78  2.892   1784    1784
Fxa 5   UN  3   85  5.932   1396    1396
Fxa 5   UN  3   54  15.144  1450    1450
Fxa 6   UN  3   123 17.045  1421    1421
Fxa 6   UN  3   124 23.166  1557    1557
Fxa 6   UN  3   110 24.056  1694    1694
Oma 1   FO  1   151 2.796   260 260
Oma 1   FO  1   153 5.072   290 290
Oma 1   FO  1   139 6.39    333 333
Oma 1   FO  1   150 9.153   320 320
Oma 2   NA  1   170 0.957   309 309
Pma 1   FO  3   141 0.759   557 557
Pma 2   FO  3   131 39.58   606 606
Pma 2   FO  3   140 40.366  548 548
Pma 3   FO  3   137 14.396  600 600
Pma 3   FO  3   135 14.94   714 714
Pma 3   FO  3   134 15.492  759 759
Pma 3   FO  3   133 23.894  669 669
```

Comment: This is not really how cross-validated works ...

Comment: Looping will (usually) be slower than vectorized computations. Often much slower.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use `ddply` from `plyr` but if it is slow then `data.table` would be the way to go, which I am sure you will get an answer for soon.

Calling you data `YouRdatA` :

```
library(plyr)

ddply(YouRdatA, .(id.indiv, local), function(x){
 data.frame( w.m.dur  = weighted.mean(x$duration, x$n.indiv, na.rm = TRUE),
             w.m.ini  = weighted.mean(x$initial.time, x$n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE),           
             w.m.fini = weighted.mean(x$freq.initial, x$n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE),
             w.m.fmin = weighted.mean(x$freq.min, x$n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE) 
            )
})
```

with `summarize`

```
ddply(YouRdatA, .(id.indiv, local), summarize, 
             w.m.dur  = weighted.mean(duration, n.indiv, na.rm = TRUE),
             w.m.ini  = weighted.mean(initial.time, n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE),           
             w.m.fini = weighted.mean(freq.initial, n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE),
             w.m.fmin = weighted.mean(freq.min, n.indiv,na.rm = TRUE) 
            )
```